# How to draw single plot with two colors in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I plotted below graph with the list of values. But the graphs are not merging. I would need the Red plot starts right after the blue plot.

```
plt.plot(x_list[:251])
plt.plot(x_list[251:],color='r')
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want two separate plots. I need single one with different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create example data

```
x_list = np.random.randint(0,100,300)
```

Make another list, fill the data till 251 with NANs:

```
y_list = [np.nan]*300
y_list[251:] = x_list[251:]
```

Plot

```
plt.plot(x_list[:251])
plt.plot(y_list,color='r')
```

**Alternative data given by OP**

```
x_list = [[26756.0], [0.0], [831.0], [23676.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [1325.0], [33293.0], [32323.000000000004], [30535.0], [32351.0], [30859.000000000004], [28416.0]]
```

Note that I put brackets around `np.nan` to be in line with the input data - which is a nested list. As the example list has length of 14, I used 10 as point to let start the second time-serie.

```
y_list = [[np.nan]]*len(x_list)
y_list[10:] = x_list[10:]
plt.plot(x_list[:10])
plt.plot(y_list, color='r')
```

An alternative would be to flatten your nested list using `list(np.array(x_list).flat)` and then continue with the first solution.

Comment: I tried this, plots are merging now but I am loosing original Y axis data. My list x_list has the values that are plotted in Y-axis.

Comment: What do you mean by "losing original Y axis data?". If you could put (a sample of) your data in the question that would be helpful.

Comment: I can't put the data. Its confidential. If you see the sample plot in description, the range is 0 to 36K in y-axis.

Comment: My list is 275 items and it ranges from 0 to 36K. I want to plot like no of items in X-axis and list of values in Y-axis

Comment: Not sure what is your error, could give more detail? If I use `np.random.randint(0,36000,300)`, so that is data in the y range you have, it is plotting it correctly.

Comment: I see its plotting correctly but my original data is getting lost. My data is something like below.

Comment: [[26756.0],
 [0.0],
 [831.0],
 [23676.0],
 [0.0],
 [0.0],
 [0.0],
 [1325.0],
 [33293.0],
 [32323.000000000004],
 [30535.0],
 [32351.0],
 [30859.000000000004],
 [28416.0]]

Comment: the code given by you is just plotting 0 to 36K but not considering my data.

Comment: I have updated the question in which you can use the data you gave in the comment.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear!